# Separation and access times in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, database-schema

In SQL Server if I have a column that is large, it's going to reduce the number of rows I can pull in a page (and presumably increase the access time).

If I remove that column from the table and put that data in a more isolated table it will increase the number of rows I can pull in a page of data.

Suppose I remove that column from the database entirely and put it in a separate database entirely. Will that decrease the seek times for everything in the database?

More generally: when does it make sense to move a column to a separate table and when should it go in a separate database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

micahhoover your question reads like a Kobayashi Maru scenario.  If the long data is mostly null and mostly not needed to be displayed then you could put it in another table so you can pack more in your pages. But if your dual table data is in SQL cache then it is occuping the same amount of space as placing it in the same table and loading the table into cache.
Placing the data into another table works well when there is an infrequent need for the data and it will be retrieved via a seperate query NOT a join during every access of the main table which will lead to the performance impace Eric J. mentioned.
Placing the data into another DB would be a disaster due to the need to syncronize the backups, log file backups etc. 
There is but one way to be sure you have the best design. The only is to benchmark several designs with REAL world data and queries.

Answer (score 1):

If the column actually needs to be accessed frequently, placing it in a separate table (or database) creates a need to join to the other table.  Nothing is saved.  In fact, performance will get worse if this specific performance consideration is the only reason for moving the column.

If you have situations where a subset of a table is frequently accessed, but you still sometimes need to access all columns, consider a [covering index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) for such queries.

Answer (score 1):

> In SQL Server if I have a column that is large, it's going to reduce
>   the number of rows I can pull in a page (and presumably increase the
>   access time).

Theoretically yes.  It depends on certain factors.  It depends on the data type, and how often that column has data in it and how much.

> If I remove that column from the table and put that data in a more
>   isolated table it will increase the number of rows I can pull in a
>   page of data.

Technically yes, but again it depends on several factors.

> Suppose I remove that column from the database entirely and put it in
>   a separate database entirely. Will that decrease the seek times for
>   everything in the database?

It depends on what you are doing with the database as far as sql server managing memory etc., but for the most part no.  I would not do this.  Joining data across databases when you don't need to is always more trouble than it's worth.  There are a lot of things to consider such has back up plans, managing database growth etc.  99% of the time, it's not worth it.

It really sounds like you are trying to do [vertical partitioning](http://structuredsight.com/2015/01/12/its-o-k-that-its-just-the-two-of-us-when-a-1x1-table-relationship-makes-sense/) for speed performance on queries.  Now in theory this **could** help, but I would guess that the amount of data you are looking at isn't going to really make this advantageous.  If you want your look ups to go faster, I would start by looking at the query execution plans, and the indexing to make sure that is all in order.

Moving fields for speed should be a last resort as it makes maintenance etc. more tedious.  This approach will also have to be explained to anyone who takes over, but the first thing they are going to question is why do all these 1x1 relationships exist, and unless they know it's been done to be a performance hack they will probably try and start logically organizing the data back to being together.